# Javascript - Property of an instance class is undefined after callback from $.post

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, jquery-callback

I have the following js snippet:

```
<script language="javascript">
          function test() {
            this.a = 10;
        };
        test.prototype.next = function () {
            alert('before: ' + this.a);
            $.ajax({
                url: 'some-url',
                async: true,
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: this.callback

            });
        };
        test.prototype.callback = function () {
            alert('after: ' + this.a);
        };

        $(document).ready(function () {
            var test1 = new test();
            test1.next();
        });
      </script>
```

It's alway produce result:
before: 10
after: undefine.

Why in the callback function of $.post, properties of class are undefined. Could anyone help me? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
success: this.callback
```

This won't work. You need to bind the callback to the instance (`this`). Otherwise it will have lost its scope. The function alone will unfortunately not remember it.

The manual way would be

```
var me = this;

// .....

success: function(x,y,z) { me.callback(x,y,z) }
```

and I cannot find the built-in helper that jQuery has for this right now. In CoffeeScript you'd just use the fat arrow `=>`.

**Update:** found the jQuery way: There is a parameter `context` that you can specify for `$.ajax`, and that will become `this` for all callbacks:

```
 success:  this.callback,
 context:  this
```

Answer (score 1):

You are loosing context so the `this` points to the different object. There is a build-in proxy function available in jQuery. Change your code as follows:

```
// ...
$.ajax({
    url: 'some-url',
    async: true,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: $.proxy(this.callback, this)
});
// ...
```

Comment: Ahh, that is what I was looking for in my answer. +1

Comment: Yeap, althought it's quite easy to write your own proxy function (like Sandeep G B bellow), but jQuery already has one.

Comment: And for `$.ajax` there is `context` which seems to be a tad more efficient (no need to construct the wrapper functions).

Comment: Great, +1. I didn't know about `context` option.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to the function closure. "this" for callback doesn't point to "test", instead to the callback function itself.

Use something like this

```
function binder (func, thisValue) {
            return function () {
                return func.apply(thisValue, arguments);
            }
        }

var bindedFun = binder(function () {
            alert('after: ' + this.a);
        }, test);
```

Comment: And with this binder (is there nothing built into jQuery for that?) you can then also write: `success: binder(this.callback, this)`.

Comment: I am not sure if there is anything available in JQuery; I am doing this way in my projects

Comment: Shouldn't you catch the arguments in the closure, then pass them to apply. Looks like arguments is gonna be empty the way you have it.

Answer (score 0):

The other way to do this is to make the callback a local function that has access to local scope and save a reference to `this` in local scope.  I think this could work fine because the callback may want access to `this`, but it doesn't necessarily have to be a method to do that.

```
    test.prototype.next = function () {
        var self = this;

        function callback() {
            alert('after: ' + self.a);
        }

        alert('before: ' + this.a);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'some-url',
            async: true,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: callback

        });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

few changes in ur code like following will do

```
<script language="javascript">
          function test() {
            this.a = 10;
        };
        test.prototype.next = function () {
            alert('before: ' + this.a);
            var oThis = this;          //Save refernce of Test() function in a varaiable. then use it 
            $.ajax({
                url: 'some-url',
                async: true,
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: oThis.callback // This is change this=> earlier was referring 
                                        //$.ajax object so save this of test() 
                                        // in a variable and then use it 
            });
        };
        test.prototype.callback = function () {
            alert('after: ' + this.a);
        };

        $(document).ready(function () {
            var test1 = new test();
            test1.next();
        });
      </script>
```